# ng-pattern changing, but form saying information is valid

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

So, the current code looks like this:

```
<input ng-pattern="validRegEx()" required>

$scope.validRegEx = function() {
  // blah blah return regex
};
```

When I change an input on the form, I change the regex. The problem is data that was valid before (which should NOT be valid with the new RegEx) is still valid. How can I force the form to apply a regex to this field again, as opposed to just waiting for the user to blur the field again?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a directive by watching for when the regex changes (or the conditions for it) and when it does you can re-run the validation by re-setting the value of the element.

something like this

```
angular.module('youappname', [])
    .directive('reApply', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            // you should change 'regex' in the following line to match the variable that when altered causes the regex to change..
            scope.$watch('regex', function (value) {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue !== ''){
                    ctrl.$setViewValue( ctrl.$viewValue );
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and adding `re-apply` to your element

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="validate()" re-apply="" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required> <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Dztev/5/

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done directly in the controller.  This will watch the input stuff.name and if it changes, it will clear the scope.stuff.results field.

```
$scope.$watch("stuff.name", function(newValue, oldValue){
  if(newValue != oldValue)
    $scope.stuff.results = "";
});
```